# How to add a sentence to end of a specifics line in text file using C?

Tags: c, text, txt

i have a text file that includes words in each line like TEST, TEST1, TEST! and i have to use 3 proccess to check these words.
**Proccess one** should check if the word consists of only letters.
**proccess two** should check if the word contains numbers,
**proccess three** should check if the word contains special characters.

Imagine that first line in text file is the word "*TEST*". Proccess one, should add "*-Only Letters-*" to end of line. These operations should be applied on the same txt file. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *filename = "kaynak.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: file not exist! %s", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    char ch;
    char line[10000];
    bool write = false;
    char sayi[10000] = "-Sayi var -";
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL){
        int i = 0;
        while(line[i] != '\0')
        {
            if(line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')
             {
                  write = true;
                  printf("Number find\n");
             }
            i++;
        }
        if(write == true)
        {
            fputs("- Number - \n", fp);      
            write = false; 
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This code replaces these lines:

```
2           
Mart'ta 
sunu8lan
```

in my sample text file with:

```
2 
- Number - 
u8lan
```

but it should be like this:

```
2 - Number -           
Mart'ta 
sunu8lan - Number -
```

How can i fix my algorithm?

Comment: You have two major problems: The first is that you try to modify the file that you read, which is tricky at best of times; And the second problem is that when you write to the file you overwrite whatever is there. To solve both problems, I recommend you read a line into memory (much like you do now), modify it to look like you want it to, then write it to a new and temporary file. Once you have copied (with or without modifications) to the new file, close both files and rename the new temporary file as the old original file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
I saw this solution while researching for the solution, but my teacher wants us to do these operations on the same txt file because these three proccesses will work at the same time and will do the writing operation sequentially.

Comment: I think you need to ask your teacher for clarifications, because doing these operations on the same file you're reading from will become *very* tricky. You need to shuffle all the data in the file when you add characters, you need to seek back and forth to get to the proper positions in the file to write the data, etc. If you're supposed to do all the modification to the file in-place, while reading, is just not really feasible as a simple assignment or exercise.

Comment: I don't see three processes, there is only one. What you can do otherwise if number of lines are less than few hundred, keep the updated records/lines in process memory; once you've reach the `EOF` dump the records in order (use `line#` to track lines)

Comment: @जलजनक This is the first part of the code, I didn't add the process phase.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is our term project for operating systems. When i asked him, he said it´s possible...

Comment: Take a piece of squared paper, write the string `hello world` on the paper, one letter per square. Now insert a letter between the `e` and the `l` in `hello`. What do you need to do with the other letters? You need to move all of them. That's what you have to do with the file as well: Every time you write a string to the file, you must move (read and rewrite) the existing contents of the file. *And* you can't really read line by line, as then you don't have the exact positions where you need to insert the string, or from where to move the existing contents.